# Comparing rows and reporting back diferences Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to use the following code to compare two Excel sheets however I can't get it to function quite as I need.  I need to compare row by row and report specific differences even when rows of data on each sheet are not necessarily in the same order.  The code reports all differences based on how the data physically exists in the tables. So it is showing differences but if the data was put into the same order in each table they wouldn't actually be differences.  Due to the nature of the data I can't sort first.  Hope this makes sense.  Could someone please suggest what changes are required to get what I need?

```
Sub Compare()
    ' compare two different worksheets in the active workbook
    CompareWorksheets Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' compare two different worksheets in two different workbooks
    'CompareWorksheets ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), _
       ' Workbooks("impchk1.xls").Worksheets("Sheet2")
End Sub

Sub CompareWorksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
Dim r As Long, c As Integer
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc1 As Integer, lc2 As Integer
Dim maxR As Long, maxC As Integer, cf1 As String, cf2 As String
Dim rptWB As Workbook, DiffCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Creating the report..."
    Set rptWB = Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    While Worksheets.Count > 1
        Worksheets(2).Delete
    Wend
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    With ws1.UsedRange
        lr1 = .Rows.Count
        lc1 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    With ws2.UsedRange
        lr2 = .Rows.Count
        lc2 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    maxR = lr1
    maxC = lc1
    If maxR < lr2 Then maxR = lr2
    If maxC < lc2 Then maxC = lc2
    DiffCount = 0
    For c = 1 To maxC
        Application.StatusBar = "Comparing cells " & Format(c / maxC, "0 %") & "..."
        For r = 1 To maxR
            cf1 = ""
            cf2 = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            cf1 = ws1.Cells(r, c).FormulaLocal
            cf2 = ws2.Cells(r, c).FormulaLocal
            On Error GoTo 0
            If cf1 <> cf2 Then
                DiffCount = DiffCount + 1
                Cells(r, c).Formula = "'" & cf1 & " <> " & cf2
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
    Application.StatusBar = "Formatting the report..."
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(maxR, maxC))
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlHairline
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Columns("A:IV").ColumnWidth = 20
    rptWB.Saved = True
    If DiffCount = 0 Then
        rptWB.Close False
    End If
    Set rptWB = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox DiffCount & " cells contain different formulas!", vbInformation, _
        "Compare " & ws1.Name & " with " & ws2.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot realistically do this without having some kind of "key" to identify the "same" row of data between sheets. Is there some column or combination of columns which should be unique per record?

Comment: ^ How can you expect to recognize a row if you're looking for differences in it? If the row isn't the same, and the order isn't the same, what is?

Comment: You need someway of mapping the rows from sheet1 to the rows in sheet2

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  All rows are unique so this is why I thought this may be possible.  I need to identify those that don't match and highlight why if possible. Example data, [link](http://www.filedropper.com/example_5)

Comment: A combination of column A,B & E should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In the worksheet that will be updated, convert each row to a string and save it to a dictionary. Then, in the worksheet you're updating from, loop through all the rows, get their string rep and see if it exists in the dictionary. If it doesn't, then add them.

Here's an example code that gets a string from a rows values

```
Sub getRowAsString()
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim arr2() As Variant
    Dim printCol As Integer

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    printCol = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1

    For Each cell In sheet.UsedRange.Rows
        arr = cell.Value2
        ReDim arr2(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2))

        For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr2(i) = arr(1, i)
        Next i

        str = Join(arr2, ", ")
        ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, printCol).value = str
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Here's an example of using a dictionary:

```
Sub createDictionary()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Key = "hello"
    value = "world"
    dict.Add Key, value

    MsgBox "key exists: " & dict.exists(Key) & vbNewLine & "value: " & dict(Key)
End Sub
```

If the string representation of a row is too large, you can save a hashed value of it into the dictionary to make it more manageable. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/550592/is-there-an-excel-function-to-create-a-hash-value) is a post that gives VBA code for hashing a string