# Find row by key excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro in vba to update information on sheet two from sheet one.  The individual records are tied together by keys.  So, one key corresponds to a record in sheet 1 and also a record in sheet two.  I have the macro start off by defining the rows that are filled with data (at this stage it only has the a column). Then it enters a for loop and gets the entire rows and compares the two rows and updates them if they aren't the same. I am not sure how I would write the line for the if statement to compare the two rows that have the same key (since they aren't going to be in sequential order). Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have posted the code that I have written so far below.

```
Sub crossUpdate()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, N As Long
Dim rng1Row As Range
Dim rng2Row As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Cell As Variant


N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Set rng1 = Sheet1.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng2 = Sheet2.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)


For i = 2 To rng1.Rows.Count
    Set rng1Row = rng1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
    Set rng2Row = rng2.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
    Key = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
        For j = 1 To rng1.Columns.Count
            If rng1Row.Cells(i, j).Value <> rng2Row.Cells(i, j).Value Then

             Else

            End If
        Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How about using application.worksheetfunction.vlookup(), with the same parameters as the worksheet vlookup, e.g. application.worksheetfunction.vlookup(Key,range,column,0).

Comment: In your code, rng1 has just one column by definition, yet you're looping on the column. Is it just because of the current testing status?

Comment: How would I implement the vlookup function? Also I am not sure why rng1 is in the loop.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you wouldn't just include vlookup formulas on Sheet 2 that reference the table of data on Sheet 1? (Like, for example, perhaps you only want the update to occur when you trigger it manually)  If there isn't a particular reason, I would suggest that formulas might be easier in this case.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have not accepted the several answers which have helped you so far? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024574/run-time-error-1004-in-excel-vba) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042844/find-specific-cell-excel-vba-macro/26042988#26042988) (last question posted under a different username, but is using the exact same `Key = Sheet1.Range...`

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085197/comparing-rows-and-reporting-back-diferences-excel-vba/25088368#25088368). The question asked how to compare rows.

My answer tried to quickly do these comparisons by storing a hash of the row. For your question, you could try converting both of the rows to a string and just comparing them like that. If they aren't equal, just copy one of the rows into the other.